# how to create a makefile with several sub-directories

Tags: c, makefile

I have one directory and underneath it 4 subdirectories like so:

```
myDir:
myDir/Part1
myDir/Part2
myDir/Part3
myDir/shared
```

I want to make an executable that takes files from shared, links it to files in Part2 and puts the executable in myDir.

This is what I tried (only the lines in the makefile that are relevant):

```
Shared/helper.o:
gcc -ansi -pedantic-errors -c -Wall -Werror -g -o Shared/helper.o Shared/helper.c
```

and above it in the makefile:

```
Part2/part2code.o: ../Shared/helper.o
gcc -ansi -pedantic-errors -c -Wall -Werror -g -o Part2/part2code.o Part2/part2code.c
```

and above it in the makefile:

```
part2code: Part2/part2code.o  ../Shared/helper.o
gcc -ansi -pedantic-errors -Wall -Werror -g -lm -o part2code Part2/part2code.o  ../Shared/helper.o
```

(I also tried without the ../ before Shared)

I get this error:

```
No such file or directory.
```

help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this context, paths in filenames are all relative to where the makefile is.  So e.g. `Part2/part2code.o: ../Shared/helper.o` is incorrect; it should simply be `Part2/part2code.o: Shared/helper.o` (and so on).  Note also that you've written `Shared` in your makefile, but you've listed your directory as `shared`...

Although actually, that's still wrong.  Rules such as `a: b` express that `b` is a *prerequisite* of `a`; i.e. that you cannot make `a` until you've made `b`.  That is not the case for your object files; they don't depend on each other.  Usually, an object file depends purely on its constituent source files (`*.c` and `*.h`).  So, for example, your rule for `part2code.o` might be something like:

```
Part2/part2code.o: Part2/part2code.c
    gcc -ansi -pedantic-errors -c -Wall -Werror -g -o $@ $^
```

(Note the use of the special variables `$@` and `$^`, which substitute in for the target and the prerequisites, respectively.)

Comment: I believe that the poster said that he tried it without the ../ .

Comment: @Konstantin: Indeed he/she did.  But with the information available, it should definitely be without.